# VB.NET Animated image class that uses a timer to advance frames - is this a good approach?

Tags: vb.net, performance, animation, timer

VB.NET, .NET 4

Hello,

I am writing an industrial control front-end that has some "fancy" graphics to indicate the states of some machinery.  For example, I indicate that some heaters are on by showing red wavy arrows emanating out from a picture of a heater.  I accomplished this by creating a class that inherits from PictureBox and using a timer to advance the images:

```
Public Class AnimatedPictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

    Private WithEvents Timer As New Timers.Timer
    Public Property Interval As Double
        Get
            Return Timer.Interval
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            Timer.Interval = value
        End Set
    End Property    

    Public ImageList As New List(Of Image)
    Private NextImageIndex As Integer = 0

    Public Sub New(ByVal Interval As Integer)
        MyBase.New()
        Timer = New Timers.Timer
        Me.Interval = Interval
        Me.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Me.Visible = True
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(100)
    End Sub

    Public Sub BeginAnimation(ByVal [Loop] As Boolean)
        Timer.Start()
    End Sub
    Public Sub BeginAnimation()
        BeginAnimation([Loop]:=True)
    End Sub
    Public Sub StopAnimation()
        Timer.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer.Elapsed
        InvokeControl(Me, _
            Sub(x)
                x.Image = x.ImageList(NextImageIndex)
                x.NextImageIndex += 1
                If x.NextImageIndex > x.ImageList.Count - 1 Then x.NextImageIndex = 0
            End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Where InvokeControl is a subroutine in a module that handles cross-thread marshalling of controls:

```
Private Sub InvokeControl(Of T As Control)(ByVal Control As T, ByVal Action As Action(Of T))
    If Control.InvokeRequired Then
        Try
            Control.Invoke(New Action(Of T, Action(Of T))(AddressOf InvokeControl), New Object() {Control, Action})
        Catch ex As Exception
            '..Handle the error..
        End Try
    Else
        Action(Control)
    End If
End Sub
```

My question is "Is this an alright way to go about this or is there some obvious better way?"  I'm not too good at programming and am worried that having several of these objects with their embedded timers taxing the CPU.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Brian

P.S.  I went with animated GIFs for some other animation stuff, but here, I wanted to be able to handle image formats that can handle a larger palette than a GIF (if that makes sense).  In other words, when I tried to save some of my animations as GIFs, the image quality took an unacceptable hit.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about several timers taxing the CPU. They don't actually do anything until they trigger your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good approach. The timers give you a lot of flexibility, and like Mike said, they won't take any CPU time to speak of.